# Angular animations query function not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

So I'm playing around with Angular animations and I have the following issue:

I have a list of posts (normal/task/event). When I load and display these posts I want them to `fadeIn` with an animation. I know how to do this with applying the same trigger to every element, but I want to keep it cleaner by using `query()` and selecting the elements I want to use the animation on by adding the class they have in common (in this case `.postEl`). Can anyone see what I did wrong?

**Template code: I want to apply the animation to the normal/event/task-post elements. I have added the `@postAnimation` trigger to the ng-container that holds these elements.**

```
<div>
        <ul class="list-group ">

<ng-container @postAnimation *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index;">
  <!-- Normal post -->
    <normal-group-post
      @slideOutRight
      class="postEl"
      *ngIf="post.type === 'normal'"
      [post]="post"
      [user]="user"
      [modules]="modules"
      [user_data]="user_data"
      [allMembersId]="allMembersId"
      [group]="group"
      [socket]="socket"
      (deletePost)="onDeletePost($event, i)"
      ng-repeat="post in posts">
    </normal-group-post>

    <!-- task post -->
    <task-group-post
      @slideOutRight
      class="postEl"
      *ngIf="post.type === 'task'"
      [post]="post"
      [user]="user"
      [isItMyWorkplace]="isItMyWorkplace"
      [modules]="modules"
      [user_data]="user_data"
      [allMembersId]="allMembersId"
      [group]="group"
      [socket]="socket"
      (deletePost)="onDeletePost($event, i)"
      ng-repeat="post in posts">
    </task-group-post>


    <!--EVENT post-->
    <event-group-post
      @slideOutRight
      class="postEl"
      *ngIf="post.type === 'event'"
      [post]="post"
      [user]="user"
      [isItMyWorkplace]="isItMyWorkplace"
      [modules]="modules"
      [user_data]="user_data"
      [allMembersId]="allMembersId"
      [group]="group"
      [socket]="socket"
      (deletePost)="onDeletePost($event, i)"
      ng-repeat="post in posts">
    </event-group-post>
</ng-container>
        </ul>

      </div>
```

**I tried to animate these elements with the below code in my component and in the shared `animate.ts` file**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-group-activity',
  templateUrl: './group-activity.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./group-activity.component.scss'],
  providers: [NgbPopoverConfig, NgbDropdownConfig],
  animations: [
    trigger('postAnimation', [
      transition('void => *', [
        query('.postEl', [
          useAnimation(fadeInAnimation)
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

**Animate.ts**

```
export let fadeInAnimation = animation([
  style({ opacity: 0 }),
  animate('{{ duration }} {{ delay }}')
], {
  params: {
    duration: '1s',
    delay: '.4s'
  }
});
```